Python - Better way to run external methods with similar, but different, names?
Currently in my project, I have some code like this in a method, where param1 and param2 are guaranteed to be the same for every function call:
def run_funct(self):

    if self.my_type == "a":
        a_funct(param1, param2)

    if self.my_type == "b":
        b_funct(param1, param2)

    if self.my_type == "c":
        c_funct(param1, param2)

Is there a way in Python to make it more like?
def run_funct(self):

    {self.my_type}_funct(param1, param2)

I've done some research online, but I don't really know what this would be called. It's not really command substitution or variable substitution, right?

You could do if self.my_type == "a": func = a_funct and such, then after, func(param1, param2), which reduces the duplication a bit. You don't want to make the name accessed dynamically though. That will be fragile, and would require either global or eval. If you have a need for this, the functions should probably be stored in something like a dictionary in the first place so the name->function mapping is explicit.

Assuming x_functs are defined at module scope, you can do something like this:
def run_funct(self):
    globals()[f'{self.my_type}_funct'](param1, param2)

But this is pretty gross, maybe rethink your design.

Right, okay - I agree with not using globals(); unfortunately the x_functs are really methods from a different class that are outside of my control. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything. Thanks!!
